# Present a modal UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

in my app delegate I do this:

```
navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homePageController] autorelease];
[tabBarController presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

for present a modal UINavigationController.
But in the homePageController how can I push other views in that navigation controller?

Should I call in the homePageController's methods this?

```
MyDelegate *delegate = (MyDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.navigationController pushViewController:newView animation:YES];
```

or should I use another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the parent navigation controller of any `UIViewController` through the `navigationController` property.  So, in your `HomePageController` methods:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
```